# Changing the target of input slider value in jQuery

Tags: jquery-slider

I'm using [JQuery Simple Slider](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/) to transform a textbox to a slider.

It includes the following script which

1. Adds a `<span class="output"></span>` after its position in the DOM and
2. Binds the value to the span when it changes.

Here it is:

```
  <script>
  $("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
      var input = $(this);
      $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
        .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
      var value = $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
          .html(data.value.toFixed(3));
    });
  </script>
```

I want to modify this so that it doesn't create a `<span>` element and displays the result somewhere else on the page.

So, I would change it to something like the following, but this doesn't work!

```
  <script>
  $("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
      var input = $(this);
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
      var value = $(this);
        $(".displayMyValue").html(data.value.toFixed(3));
    });
  </script>
```

Could I change the .nextAll to something more appropriate?

My HTML:

```
<span class="displayMyValue"></span>
<input id="my-input" type="text" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1000,100000" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-theme="volume">
<span class="output">//this created by jQuery//</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code:

```
$("[data-slider]").bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
     $(this).next("span").html(data.value.toFixed(0));
});
```

The bind function searches for the Next span which is used to display the data.

Change the "span" into `#IdSpan` and it will find the span with the defined ID.